# Confidence interval in Chi squared testing

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, chi-squared-test, ab-test

How to calculate confidence interval when performing a Chi-Square significance testing? 
For reference where it's used - http://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/chi-squared.html

Can we apply the same assumptions as of a continuous metric and apply calculations used in 2 sample t-test? I am not sure if that will be an appropriate assumption to make. 
Similar to this -  https://www.socscistatistics.com/confidenceinterval/default4.aspx

Comment: You need to estimate something first before you compute an interval about it so what do you want to estimate?

Comment: You should give more details, and possible an example data set (maybe as a contingency table?).  If you are testing homogeneity in a $2\times 2$ contingency table, you could estimate/make CI for the odds ratio. Without more details this Q will have to be closed as unclear.